# Xamarin Forms error: Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When starting debugging of my project on the Android emulator I receive this error:

Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat

At this code:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("clocker.db3");

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new Clocker.App(dbPath));
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this row:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

I have tried looking online at the other suggestions but the answers seem related to specific Xamarin studio files which are non-existant in my project (i.g. the gradle file).

I have checked the contents of 'bundle' and it seems to be null at the time of the error but I'm unsure if this is causing the error.

I'm using Xamarin forms PCL.

Comment: Can you put your source code somewhere so we can try to reproduce an fix?

Answer (score 1):

This error may occurs with several class if the project path is too long, because it go through the limit of Operational System character length.

Example of Long path:

C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio xxxx\Projects\Project Name

Example of Good path:

C:\Projects\ProjectName

EDIT - Added how the packages should look:

[image: Packages Pic]

Comment: This is already how my path is setup. There is also no 'path too long' error.

Comment: Try to update or Reinstall the Xamarin.Forms package via nuget. And DO NOT update one package from Xamarin.Droid manually. the Xamarin.Forms should handle it version.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've done this a few times but will try it again. Should I update at the solution or project level?

Comment: @connersz Project Level. Make sure to dont update any package from Prefix Xamarin.Android.Support Manually. You will update Xamarin.Forms and all others will be waiting update. Make sure to **do not** update.

Comment: To make it easy, just uninstall all Android.Support and Xamarin.Forms, and try to install again without update the Xamarin.Android..xxx

Comment: OK so I am first uninstalling all of the support items listed and then the forms. I will then install forms and it should by my understanding setup the support stuff?

Comment: When you install the Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin.Droid project level, it should automatically install all the Support stuff.

Comment: You can check at my GitHub an Example on how my project is setup: i Call it my Template: https://github.com/AndersonOki/XamarinMaterialDesign

Comment: I now have 29 errors after doing this, mostly missing namespaces like Xamarin, contentpage, etc. I also have most of the support items showing in the updates section on nuget.

Comment: Just ignore the updates on the support items. Check your references if you have any with a yellow triangle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126919/discussion-between-anderson-oki-and-connersz).

Comment: Ok, I've solved most of them but now see: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.2.0.45\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets. Clocker.Droid

Answer (score 0):

The error `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` means that you're missing a class. It tells you which class you're missing as well: `android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat`. I've not used Xamarin myself, but their documentation describes how to [use Java classes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/) in C# code. Once the package which includes the class `android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat` (VectorDrawableCompat.java, which is in [android.support.graphics.drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html) I think?) is imported, your code should run.

Comment: I have added all of the classes that stand out as being a possible solution but nothing works. It's difficult to know what to add with hundreds available.

Comment: Thankfully you don't need to look through hundreds of classes. Your error message tells you where to look. I've updated my answer with a link to the appropriate android docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but look at the way the MainActivity is declared.

Your example has:

- public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity

But in my code i have:

- public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity

See if that makes a difference to the startup.
If you have to use FormsAppCompatActivity then see if changing the Api level to the highest supported level makes a difference.

Do you have any logs from the Output window, Show Xamarin Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I resolved it to install the latest version of [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and select the new folder in Visual Studio.

[image: Xamarin Setting on Visual Studio 2015]